# Is there a way to call Excel VBA function from Power Query M?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery

Is there a way to call Excel VBA function from Power Query M to obtain value for further processing?

It is possible to get cell value via M function, but I also want to get value from Text Box.
In VBA I can get that text, but I could  not find if I can call that Excel VBA function from M query.

In more details:
I actually want to get JSON to parse with Power Query. It works perfectly if I go with "Get Data from File JSON". But it makes the spreadsheet dependent on the location of the file, if I send it to other user, the user should place JSON file into the same location as on my computer which present some complications.
I tried to copy that JSON file into single Excel cell. It works but it looks like there is a limitation for the file size, my files are bigger that Excel allows in the cell.
Other solution would be to place that JSON text into Text Box. I can extract the context from Text Box with VBA but I cannot get it into Power Query.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In powerquery you can have someone put a location in a named range, then grab the filepath from the named range (cell) by using

```
let NameValue= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="rangenamehere"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(NameValue), null, true),
```

Or if you wanted the VBA route for file prompt, have the VBA call the PowerQuery, not the other way around

1 Create a range name, here aaa

2 Use VBA to populate it using a file prompt

```
Sub prompt()
Dim FName As Variant
FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", "Data file (*.xl*),*.xl*", 1)
If FName = False Then
MsgBox "False"
Exit Sub
End If
Range("aaa").Value = FName
End Sub
```

3 Refer to the named range in powerquery you set up

```
let NameValue= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="aaa"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents(NameValue), null, true),
```

4 Tack on code at end of VBA to refresh all queries or specific query

```
ActiveWorkbook.RefreshAll
```

or

```
ActiveWorkbook.Queries("QueryNameHere").Refresh
```